AutoCad lisp that copy value from selected block by click and paste it to another block, to specific attribute
AutoCad lisp: select block, copy value from block's attribute  (in my case) "VISINA", select another block and paste into block's attribute (in my case) "RELATIVNA".
enter image description here
enter image description here
Since I am new to autocad lisp, I tried to find similar lisp on web, and tried to change it but didn't work in my case.

Here's an example:
(defun c:TEST (/ b a)
  (cond
    ((null (setq b (car (entsel "\nSelect source block: "))))
     (prompt "None selection.")
    )
    ((/= (cdr (assoc 0 (entget b))) "INSERT")
     (prompt "Selected entity is not a block.")
    )
    ((vl-catch-all-error-p
       (setq a (vl-catch-all-apply 'getpropertyvalue (list b "VISINA")))
     )
     (prompt "Selected block does not have a 'VISINA' attribute."
     )
    )
    ((null (setq b (car (entsel "\nSelect target block: "))))
     (prompt "None selection.")
    )
    ((/= (cdr (assoc 0 (entget b))) "INSERT")
     (prompt "Selected entity is not a block.")
    )
    ((vl-catch-all-error-p
       (vl-catch-all-apply 'setpropertyvalue (list b "RELATIVNA" a))
     )
     (prompt
       "Selected block does not have a 'RELATIVNA' attribute."
     )
    )
  )
  (princ)
)

Another example which works with any selected attributes:
(defun c:TEST (/ a1 l1 a2 l2)
  (cond
    ((null (setq a1 (car (nentsel "\nSelect source attribute: "))))
     (prompt "None selection.")
    )
    ((/= (cdr (assoc 0 (setq l1 (entget a1)))) "ATTRIB")
     (prompt "Selected entity is not an attribute.")
    )
    ((null (setq a2 (car (nentsel "\nSelect target attribute: "))))
     (prompt "None selection.")
    )
    ((/= (cdr (assoc 0 (setq l2 (entget a2)))) "ATTRIB")
     (prompt "Selected entity is not an attribute.")
    )
    (T (setpropertyvalue
     (cdr (assoc 330 l2))
     (cdr (assoc 2 l2))
     (getpropertyvalue
       (cdr (assoc 330 l1))
       (cdr (assoc 2 l1))
     )
       )
    )
  )
  (princ)
)

